# Equality check for two boolean expressions (TSQL)

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have two tables and I want to join two tables based on the sign of the related columns

I'm joining on the `condition a<0 = b<0` but the equality sign gives me a syntax error. I don't want to do (`a<0 AND b<0`) OR (`Not a<0 AND Not b<0`) because it doesn't look clean

Comment: You could use `SIGN()` function, although dealing with `0` values makes resulting code inelegant either.

Comment: Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database. In this case [`IIF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql) might be applicable.

Comment: @Arvo Your answer has been posted. It's nice to know there is another fan of `Sign()` out there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You know what the answer is:

```
where (a < 0 and b < 0) or (a >= 0 and b >= 0)
```

SQL Server doesn't treat boolean values as *bona fide* values, so you cannot treat them as regular values in other types of expressions.

You can express this using bitwise or (`'^'`) if you really want:

```
where (case when a < 0 and b < 0 then 1 else 0 end) ^ (case when a >= 0 and b >= 0 then 1 else 0 end) = 1
```

However, I find that rather inscrutable.

Answer (score 1):

As Arvo suggested, you can use `Sign()`. Assuming that `a` and `b` are integer types:

```
where Sign( Sign( a ) + 1 ) = Sign( Sign( b ) + 1 )
```

Explanation: The inner `Sign()` calls convert the input values to -1, 0 or 1. Adding 1 shifts those values to 0, 1 or 2. The outer `Sign()` calls collapse that back to 0 or 1 representing negative and non-negative inputs.

This kind of code is occassionally useful, but should be accompanied by a comment explaining the intent. If the technique is truly impenetrable then it should be explained in the comment or a citation provided.

Answer (score 0):

Comparison of boolean types is not in the list of supported SQL Server operators:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/logical-operators-transact-sql

So to test `A == B` you write (both true or both false):

```
(A AND B) OR (NOT A AND NOT B)
```

In other answers above is rewritten into:

```
(a < 0 and b < 0) or (a >= 0 and b >= 0)
```

Alternative boolean expression is:

```
(A OR NOT B) AND (NOT A AND B)
# meaning: A => B & B => A, so A <=> B.
```